# Android Google Places API, Autocomplete me retorna el estado 'PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED'

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

Cuando intento abrir el autocomplete de google places, me sale la ventana luego se cierra retornandome el error mencionado.
mi codigo  para abrir el autocomplete es esto :

```
 Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                                .build(MapsActivity.this);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

y el activity result me debe mostrar el lugar seleccionado

```
// A place has been received; use requestCode to track the request.
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);
             //   Log.i(TAG,"Place: " + place.getName() );
                tvUbicacion.setText("Place: " + place.getName());
            } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
                Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
                // TODO: Handle the error.
              //  Log.i(TAG, );
                tvUbicacion.setText("Estado: " +status.getStatusMessage());

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // The user canceled the operation.
                tvUbicacion.setText("Cancelado");
            }
        }
    }
```

ya he configurado la api key   en el manifest

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

El mapa si me carga ,pero el autocomplete se cierra, y no me muestra.
En console cloud  ya he configurado y me muestra api , habilitada.

Answer (score 0):

**El mensaje indica que la API Google Places no esta habilitada, ingresa a la consola y habilita la API**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta forma habilitaras la API  Google Places para tu Key

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comentas que has habilitado la API, entonces probablemente agregaste una restricción, debes asegurar que el "package name" de la aplicación sea el correcto y el código SHA-1 sea el correcto, regularmente se registran 2, uno para debug y otro para la aplicación cuando sea liberada a Google Play Store.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Asegura también que el valor especificado de la API en `strings.xml` sea el indicado en la consola:

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

Comment: en verdad hice todo eso,ya he habilitado google place, pero no funciona.

Comment: Revisa que la Api Key sea la misma que tienes definida en Strings.xml, definiste una restricción a la API key? @JhonJesus

Comment: si ,que raro por que no me sale.

Comment: Debes ver si en el proyecto que habilitaste la API es el mismo del cual obtienes la API. El nombre del proyecto lo puedes ver en mi imagen, donde dice "Proyect Test"